# Aligning a textbox next to a label

Tags: html, css

I have a text box aligned below a label. But I need the text box to be aligned next to a label.

I am adding a code snippet.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="label" class="control-label">Total Work days in Current Month:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="header" ng-model="currentmonth" placeholder="Enter the details" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Read more about `form-inline` and `form-horizontal` [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```

**or**

Use `form-horizontal`

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

we can fix this different ways

first we can fix this with `flex` property

```css
.form-group { 
 display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="label" class="control-label">Total Work days in Current Month:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="header" ng-model="currentmonth" placeholder="Enter the details" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or we can fix this with `inline-block`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
#label {
  display:inline-block;
}
.form-control {
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
</style>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="label" class="control-label">Total Work days in Current Month:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="header" ng-model="currentmonth" placeholder="Enter the details" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-flex;` to the `form-group` class. and set the width accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `form-inline` class to your row element ( Note: this needs your viewport to be atleast 768px wide.  LYpu won't be able to have this work on mobile devices. ) or 
You can have 2 columns for this. One containing the label and another with the input.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label><font color="red">*</font>
    <input name="name"  type="text" class="form-control" value="" size="30" required="true"/>
    <div id="message">
    </div>
</div>
```